# Wrong Positioning of UIScrollView in Xcode 5 and iOS 7 with Auto Layout

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, autolayout

I'm very confused about this problem I experienced today. I created a UIScrollView in Storyboard and made some Auto Layout stuff.

In the code I added a button to it with the y-value of 0. But as I run the app the button wasn't at zero. It was somewhere in the middle. When I check to y-value of the UIScollview in Storyboard I get 64 px.
Normally when I put zero as y-value of the button the button should be at the top of the ScrollView.

[image: Screenshot of App]

Where's the conflict? Thanks in advance.

Best regards from Germany,
Chris

Answer (score 2):

By mistake I found the solution to the problem.

See the pic :) You have to uncheck "Adjust Scroll View Insets"

[image]

That' all :)

Comment: This pointed me in the right direction, many thanks! Let me add that if you don't have a representation of your VC in the xib, you can switch it off programmatically in the VC's init method with `[self setAutomaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets:NO];`